# When XSLT transformation playing video stops in IE8

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am using sarissa library to transform xslt. when click on menu item it displayed the content of that menu at that time if video was played its stop in IE8 for a fraction of second. It works fine in other browser.

here is the link:
http://183.182.86.34:92/flowplayer/Home.html

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Does it stop playing in IE 5 or IE8? I am actually able to view it without any errors in IE8.
In IE 5 there's an error that stops the webpage from working as expected, but clicking on the frame where the video should be in IE5 opens the video seperately, so it still does work. 
To debug and locate the exact error, use the IE developer tool by clicking F12 or Tools-Developer Tools. Click 'Script' tab and 'Start Debugging'. Allow to refresh page. 
You might want to add browser compatibility checks using a javascript or styles, or fix the error by checking the flowplayer documentation.

http://flowplayer.org/documentation/developer/writing-javascript-plugins.html

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=540#start

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 19 May 2011 15:02:46 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 186
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://183.182.86.34:92/flowplayer/Home.html